# VHDL: Instantation question

Tags: vhdl

I have to do a instantation of several components

[image]

I suppose the code for this instantation would be something like this:

```
componentA: componentB port map(
output_ca => input_cb
); 
componentA: componentC port map(
output_ca => input_cc
);
```

But I know that part of the code before is wrong, because 'ouput_ca' has 6 bits and input_cb, and input_cc has only 3 bits every one of them.
**How would be written this code in a good way?** 
Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 6):

You must use some signals, you can't map straight from one pin to another (I'm also using direct instantiation to avoid creating `component` declarations - see also [my answer here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/16692/vhdl-component-vs-entity/16700#16700)):

```
signal aout : std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);

A: entity work.componentA port map(
    output_pin => aout
); 
B: entity work.componentB port map(
    input_pin => aout(5 downto 3)
); 
C: entity work.componentC port map(
    input_pin => aout(2 downto 0)
);
```

---

## Aside

You seem to be confused in your instantiation syntax.  You wrote:

```
componentA:componentB port map (...
```

implying that componentA connects to component B.

What is actually being said is

```
individual_name_of_component: name_of_entity
```

So you pick an `entity` which you are instantiating on the right of the `:` and give it a name on the left.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about direct instantiation.  I always hated keeping component declarations in sync.