# How does a structural architecture know which entity to use?

Tags: vhdl, components

So I'm following [this](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~ese171/vhdl/vhdl_primer.html) tutorial in which they explain some basic VHDL by using a four bit adder as an example:

```
-- Example of a four bit adder
library  ieee;
use  ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

-- definition of a full adder
entity FULLADDER is
     port (a, b, c: in std_logic;
           sum, carry: out std_logic);
     end FULLADDER;
architecture fulladder_behav of FULLADDER is
begin
sum <= (a xor b) xor c ;
carry <= (a and b) or (c and (a xor b));
     end fulladder_behav;
     -- 4-bit adder

library  ieee;
use  ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity FOURBITADD is
     port (a, b: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
           Cin : in std_logic;
                sum: out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
                Cout, V: out std_logic);
     end FOURBITADD;
architecture fouradder_structure of FOURBITADD is
     signal c: std_logic_vector (4 downto 0);
component FULLADDER
           port(a, b, c: in std_logic;
sum, carry: out std_logic);
           end component;
begin
           FA0: FULLADDER
                port map (a(0), b(0), Cin, sum(0), c(1));
           FA1: FULLADDER
                port map (a(1), b(1), C(1), sum(1), c(2));
           FA2: FULLADDER
                port map (a(2), b(2), C(2), sum(2), c(3));
           FA3: FULLADDER
                port map (a(3), b(3), C(3), sum(3), c(4));
           V <= c(3) xor c(4);
           Cout <= c(4);
end fouradder_structure;
```

I am trying to understand why the `component` part in the `fouradder_structure` has to redefine the ports used in the FULLADDER entity; they both contain the following parts:

```
port(a, b, c: in std_logic;
sum, carry: out std_logic);
```

I then read [somewhere](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/16692/vhdl-component-vs-entity#answer-16696) that `component` defines the interface that the `fouradder_structure` is expecting. That would explain why `entity` and `component` both need to declare the used ports, but then how does the `fouradder_structure` know to use the `FULLADDER` entity that was defined previously? Is it a naming convention?

**TL;DR**, how is the architecture `fouradder_structure` aware it has to use the entity `FULLADDER`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't specify which architecture an entity instantiation is going to use, it uses the most recently compiled architecture for that entity.

Personally I would use direct entity instantiation. To use this, delete the component declaration (`component FULLADDER ...`), and instantiate it thus:

```
FA0: entity work.FULLADDER(fulladder_behav)
port map ( ...
```

In this way you can easily see which architecture is being used, and you save yourself having to maintain a component declaration as well as the instantiation.

If you don't want to do this for some reason, look at using `configuration`s.

Comment: How would you specify the architecture to use?

Comment: @user1534664 I updated my answer, hope that helps.

Comment: Your answer is complete now :) Thanks for the fast reply.

Comment: I hate the component declarations. Unfortunately they are necessary in VHDL 1987 (no typo) which is still required by many synthesis tools. Though VHDL 2008 or at least VHDL 1993 is gaining ground.

Comment: @Michael which tools don't even support VHDL'93? That surely deserves a name and shame!

Answer (score 1):

You can control which entity (and which of its architectures) is bound to a specific component (provided they have compatible interfaces, i.e. port and generic lists) using a `configuration` statement. This can be either part of the architecture - an embedded configuration - or a separately compiled unit e.g. in a separate file.

If you don't bother with configurations, you 'll get the default configuration. Or you can bypass both components and configurations with direct entity instantiation - both of these approaches are described in Jeff's answer. (Direct entity instantiation is simplest and often seems to be the preferred approach nowadays).